# Inserting an item into serialized array mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

Is there any easy way to insert another key value into serialized array php mysql?

### My serialized codes are:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Sample array";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:5:"Apple";i:1;s:6:"Orange";}}
```

### And array from it is:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Sample array
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Apple
        [1] => Orange
   )
)
```

Is there any way to add `[2] => mango` ?

### Like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Sample array
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Apple
        [1] => Orange
        [2] => mango
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't mess with the serialized string. You have to be absolutely PERFECT in your modifications, or you corrupt the whole thing.

The easiest/safest method is to unserialize back to a native array, modify that, then re-serialize.

```
$foo = "a:2:etc..."
$temp = unserialize($foo);
$temp[1][2] = 'mango';
$foo = serialize($temp);
```